# Does the following linear transformation exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3$, where $\{0\}  \neq \operatorname{Ker} \space \phi \subsetneq \operatorname{Im} \space \phi $

If a linear transformation like this exists, give a concrete example. If not, then prove that a linear transformation like this can't exist.

I came across this problem while studying for my linear algebra final exam, and I can't figure it out. I know that because $\{0\} \neq \operatorname{Ker} \;\phi $ therefore it isn't injective, but I got nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

You can take $\phi(x,y,z)=(y,z,0)$. Clearly, $\ker\phi=\{(x,0,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Besides, $\operatorname{Im}\phi=\{(x,y,0):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.